# What is the right way to store an immutable Path in a struct?

Tags: path, rust, ownership

The following code works but not sure if it is the right way. A few questions:

- Should I use `Path` or `PathBuf`?
- Should I use `AsRef`?
- Do I need `PathBuf::from(path)` in order to have path owned by the struct?

```
use std::fmt;
use std::path::PathBuf;

struct Example {
    path: PathBuf,
}

impl fmt::Display for Example {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.path.to_str().unwrap())
    }
}

impl Example {

    fn new(path: &PathBuf) -> Example {
        // Do something here with path.
        Example {
            path: PathBuf::from(path),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Example::new(&PathBuf::from("test.png"));
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Some context: I am trying to have a high-level abstraction over a file that should know its own path. Maybe the design is plain wrong.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This question is almost the same as `String` vs `&str` , if that helps. `PathBuf` is `String`, `&Path` is `&str`. So:

Store a `PathBuf` if you want the struct to own it. If you don't know what you want, start here.

Store a `&Path` if you just want a reference to a path. Depending on what you're doing, this may be what you want, but if you don't know, it's probably not correct.

Comment: `Box<Path>` is another option. Since it signals immutability, it worth considering too.

Comment: It is, but I don't think I've ever seen one in all my years of writing Rust.